# Nested while-loops php

Tags: php, while-loop

I am breaking my neck over this problem. So I have a text file "$file" that I am reading line by line with the first while-loop. This is working; when I echo the "$usertext" in there, it prints nicely all the lines that are in the file.

So I want to use the $usertext as a condition for my DB query and then loop through all the rows of the DB that meet that condition. Somehow only the last line of $usertext gets in the while-loop (it is the only one that gets printed when I echo $usertext in the second while-loop).

Why do not all lines of my text file go through the second while-loop?

```
if ($file) {
 while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
  $usertext = $line;
  echo $usertext."\n";

  $result = $db->query("SELECT user, artist, artist_mbid, track, track_mbid, COUNT(*) as playcount FROM users WHERE user='$usertext' GROUP BY artist, track, user");

  while($row=$result->fetchArray()){
   echo $usertext."\n"; 
     //I also used $row["user"]; does not make any difference
  }
 } 
}
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why it wouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More likely to be data not found than an SQL error as an SQL error would stop the processing.

The output of `fgets()`, AFAIK, includes the line break. This would mean that the contents of `$usertext` might contain a line break on every record except the last, so only the last call to `$result->fetchArray()` would give an output record and so enter the `while` loop.

My advice is to try changing this line:

```
$usertext = $line;
```

To

```
$usertext = trim($line);
```

which would remove any unwanted line breaks / white space.

Answer (score 0):

`$result->fetchArray()` might return a falsey value for some of your result sets.

Make sure `$usertext` is getting inserted into the query correctly and does not break it, as well as making sure there actually are rows to be returned.

Comment: There are lines to be returned. It shows when I change the order in the text file. How do I make sure that $usertext is inserted correctly?

Comment: The query outputs just fine, but only from the last entry of $usertext (tried different orders).